# Adverb for 'within a short timeframe'

Tags: phrase-requests, adverbs

> Please come by the Secretary's Office so we can solve your problem [on the spot].

What I want to say instead of the placeholder is that as soon as the person comes to the office (be it today or in a week), we will be able to solve their problem in a short amount of time (as opposed to doing the e-mail dance between the three parties involved and dragging the problem on forever).

Is "on the spot" correct and appropriate for that, or are there better wordings?

Comment: I have removed the side question, as it is both unrelated to the question at hand and [has been asked and answered before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77472/is-there-any-rule-about-splitting-phrasal-verbs).

Comment: @RegDwight, thanks for editing my question and making it much more readable. My apologies for re-asking a question answered in the past.

Comment: on the spot is absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use any of the following:

"without delay",
"post-haste",
"immediately",
"there and then".

Comment: I like "there and then" the most, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**promptly**

-with little or no delay.