# Can you end a sentence with "properly"?

Tags: word-order

What would be the *most* correct way of option from below?

1. "As the car's oil had not been changed properly"
2. "As the car's oil had not been properly changed"

Effectively they are the same and do the same thing but is one preferable?

Comment: Why do you think one might be preferable? Why do you think there is such a thing as the _most correct_?

Comment: Related: [Is there any rule about splitting phrasal verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77472/is-there-any-rule-about-splitting-phrasal-verbs).